# draw a header-less table using jspdf autotable

Tags: jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I'm looking to draw a header-less table using jspdf autotable
I know i have to return false in drawHeader, but this name after v3.0.0 had change.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');
doc.text(20,20,'title');
var res = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(table);
doc.autoTable(res.columns, res.data,{
  theme: 'grid',
  showHead: 'never'
});
doc.save("name.pdf");
```